# Could not cast value of type `enum` to 'Swift.CVarArg'

Tags: swift, core-data, enums

I have an enum that looks like the following:

```
enum Period: String {

    case first    = "1st"
    case second   = "2nd"
    case third    = "3rd"
    case overtime = "Overtime"
}
```

I'm storing the value in CoreData, however, when I try to do the following predicate, I'm getting the following error.

```
let predicatePeriod = NSPredicate(format: "%K = %@", #keyPath(Shifts.period), period as! CVarArg)

Could not cast value of type 'Time_on_Ice.Period' (0x1052fad10) to 'Swift.CVarArg' (0x10a1a3b88).
```

The compiler is forcing me at add `as! CVarArg` prior period was an `Int` before I made it an `enum`.

Update:

```
extension Shifts {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Shifts> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Shifts>(entityName: "Shifts")
    }

    @NSManaged public var date: NSDate?
    @NSManaged public var period: String?
    @NSManaged public var timeOnIce: Int16
    @NSManaged public var gameRelationship: Games?
    @NSManaged public var playersRelationship: Players?

}
```

Comment: might you post `Shifts` code?

Comment: What type has Shifts.period?

Comment: Shifts is `Shifts: NSManagedObject` see above edit.

Comment: Did you tried with `period.rawValue` ?

Comment: @AntonMalmygin Thanks that works...